# Random AutoNumber in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am New in MS Access My Question is How to make AutoNumber Column to make an Random Numbers but with some Condition like Make Number from 10 digits only and Positive

Comment: Did you research this?  From memory, autonumber exists to make unique numbers and even set to random you can't control the format, signing etc.

Comment: I google it a lot but I didn't Find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know:

There **is** an option to Randomly generate an AutoNumber column. There **isn't** an option to make them *only* positive and 10 digits.

I actually use this in one of my tables, and *typically* the length is 8+ digits, however there are negative numbers. Neither fits your criteria.

If you go to the design view of your Table, select the column in question. Make sure the Data Type is `AutoNumber`, and locate the `Field Properties` pane at the bottom. You can select `Random` in the `New Values` dropdown list.

Unfortunately, I think you would have to take this into your own hands and create a public function to do this for you.